# CUIT (Coded UI Tests) - find the dynamic controls

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-controls, coded-ui-tests

I am developing an automated testing application to test a web application. here i am unable to Locate the controls which are being created by the web application code dynamically. their properties keep changing.

**Example:** Some controls will not appear in first time execution, but they will appear in next execution. The web application will also create an XML file to store the information of all of the controls in the web page.

Comment: Have you checked out Seleno or SpecsFor.Mvc both have ways to find dynamic controls, also see http://www.mehdi-khalili.com/presentations/auit-qmsdnug

Answer (score 1):

Tu Huynh.

I've used [CUITe (Coded UI Test enhanced Framework)](http://cuite.codeplex.com) which can do this.

For example, [changeset 21564](http://cuite.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/21564) has a sample unit test in Sample_CUITeTestProject\BrowserWindowTests.cs as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
[WorkItem(608)]
public void GenericGet_WithHtmlControls_GetsControlsDynamically()
{
    //Arrange
    CUITe_BrowserWindow bWin = CUITe_BrowserWindow.Launch("http://mail.google.com", "Gmail: Email from Google");

    //Act
    bWin.Get<CUITe_HtmlEdit>("Id=Email").SetText("xyz@gmail.com");
    bWin.Get<CUITe_HtmlPassword>("Id=Password").SetText("MyPa$$Word");
    bWin.Get<CUITe_HtmlInputButton>("Id=signIn").Click();
    bWin.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the problem in CodedUI a long back, and I resolved it by editing the property of the control. I recommend you to,

(1) Go to the properties of the dynamic control that you want to locate,

(2) you could find that the **propertyName, PropertyExpressionOperator & PropertyValue**.

`*(example : propertyName = id,

            PropertyExpressionOperator = equals,

            PropertyValue = button12)*`

(3) Now change **PropertyExpressionOperator**  (*ie equals*) to "contains", and remove the value that keeps changing in the **PropertyValue** ( *ie button12 -> button*)

(4) so the property would look like

`*(example : propertyName = id,

            PropertyExpressionOperator = contains,

            PropertyValue = button)*`

(5) Now you can able to locate it.

believe it helps you.